# React-Redux/Jest Invariant Violation: Could not find "store"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, create-react-app

I have a simple test file set up that is almost identical to the one used by create-react-app:

**App.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { App } from './App';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
});
```

When I run `yarn test` I keep getting this error message:

`Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "st
ore" as a prop to "Connect(App)".`

I have tried doing separate exports in my App.js file and importing the non-Redux component, but I still can't get this to work. Here are my other two files that are involved:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import TableList from './containers/table_list';
import Header from './components/header';
import Footer from './components/footer';

import './style/App.css';

// use named export for unconnected component (for tests)
export class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      recentUsers: [],
      allTimeUsers: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.all([this.fetchRecentUsers(), this.fetchAllTimeUsers()])
      .then(axios.spread((recentUsers, allTimeUsers) => {
        this.setState({ recentUsers: recentUsers.data, allTimeUsers: allTimeUsers.data });
    }))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      });
  }

  fetchRecentUsers() {
    return axios.get(RECENT);
  }

  fetchAllTimeUsers() {
    return axios.get(ALLTIME);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
          <div className="container">
            <TableList users={this.state.recentUsers} />
          </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => (
  { recentUsers: state.recentUsers, allTimeUsers: state.allTimeUsers }
)

// use default export for the connected component (for app)
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

import rootReducer from './reducers/index';
import App from './App';
import './style/index.css';

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

What am I overlooking here? The app works properly on its own, but I can't figure out for the life of me why the test is failing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the code you submitted, you should not have the error you specified. In order to test without decorating your component with `Redux`, you want your test to import you `App` component like this:

```
import { App } from './App'
```

Which you already did! However, the output from your test looks like you did have it like this at some point:

```
import App from './App'
```

So check again, make sure you saved your test file, etc...

Comment: Turns out I was revising my old App.test.js file... don't know how I overlooked that. Thanks for the reassurance that I wasn't losing my mind!